# my script js does not change my photo src

Tags: javascript, html

I would like to add images dynamically and have the image slider. I wrote some script, and in console I see changing src, but in HTML tere is still one picture.
Here is a code:

HTML:

```
<div class="sliderItau">
   <a class="prevButton"> <img alt="prevButton" src="/images/prev.png"></a>
   <div class="jcarousel">
     <img id="image" src="/images/debito/itau_tela_02.png" alt=""></div>
   <a class="nextButton"><img alt="nextButton" src="/images/next.png"></a>
</div>
```

JS:

```
const images = []

let slideIndex = 1

function preload_images() {

    var image = new Image()
    image.src = 'images/debito/itau_tela_01.png'
    images[0] = image
    image = new Image()
    image.src = 'images/debito/itau_tela_02.png'
    images[1] = image
    image = new Image()
    image.src = 'images/debito/itau_tela_03.png'
    images[2] = image

}

preload_images()

const showSlidesItau = function (n) {
    let img = document.getElementById('image')
    let slides = img.src
    slides = images[slideIndex].src
    console.log(slides)
    console.log(images[slideIndex].src)
    if (n > slides.length) {
        slideIndex = 1
    }
    if (n < 1) {
        slideIndex = slides.length
    }
}

const plusSlides = function (n) {
    console.log(slideIndex)
    showSlidesItau((slideIndex += n))
}

const next = document.querySelector('.nextButton')
const prev = document.querySelector('.prevButton')
//buttons ITAU
next.addEventListener('click', function () {
    plusSlides(+1)
})
prev.addEventListener('click', function () {
    plusSlides(-1)
})
```

So every time I press the button prev or next my src in colse has change. But not in HTML. Any idea why?

Comment: `slides = images[slideIndex].src` – you're changing the `slides` variable, not the element. You need to change the attribute directly: `img.src = images[slideIndex].src`

Comment: wow! great. I didnt think about it :) Thank you :)

Comment: @GuyIncognito I think you should phrase an answer from your comment so the question asker can accept it as this obviously solved the issue.

Comment: Meh. It's basically a typo and there must be countless duplicates.

Answer (score 1):

I am not a JS-Pro, but I wanted to point out a few things.
As GuyIncognito already wrote in the comments, you have to set the src-attribute directly, not on a copied variable. But there are some more flaws in your `showSlidesItau()` function:

**Do your checks before setting the image source - not after**

If `n` or `slideIndex` is out of the index range of your image array, you will still try to set it and receive an error.

**Set your slideIndex to n**

Otherwise the only times the image will change, is when the you are at the beginning or end of your image array...

**Array indices start at 0 and end at array.length -1**

So if you try something like array[array.length] you will receive an error.

I tried to rewrite the function a little bit:

```js
const showSlidesItau = function (n) {
  let img = document.getElementById("image");
  // First check the index
  if (n >= images.length) {
    slideIndex = 0;
  } else if (n < 0) {
    slideIndex = images.length - 1;
  } else {
    slideIndex = n;
  }
  // then set the src attribute
  img.src = images[slideIndex].src;
  console.log(images[slideIndex].src);
};
```

I hope I could help you a bit.